# Math giving incorrect results with value obtained from scanf()

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that can, given one, convert between to all four of Kilometers, Miles, Nautical Miles, and Furlongs given one of the four. My Main function looks like:

```
int main() {
    Scale scale; // declared in the header file "length.h"
    double value, kilometers, miles, nautical_miles, furlongs;
    // prompt user for unit to convert from
    printf("\nPlease select which unit you want to convert from:\n");
    printf("1. Kilometers\n2. Miles\n3. Nautical Miles\n4. Furlongs\n");
    scanf("%d", &scale);
    // Get value user wants
    printf("Enter value for unit you selected: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    int err = convertLength(&kilometers, &miles, &nautical_miles, &furlongs, scale);
    printf("value given was %d\n", value);
    kilometers *= value;
    //kilometers *= 2;
    //kilometers = kilometers * value;
    printf("%g Kilos\n%g miles\n%g naut mi\n%g fur", kilometers, miles, nautical_miles, furlongs);
    return 0;
}
```

The conversion is taking place in the file "length.c" and I have only been debugging the kilometers case so far. The Enum declaration for scale is in a header file "length.h".

The issue is that when I multiply kilometers in main() by value, I get an incorrect result (such as 4.940e-324). However, when I only multiply by a constant, like the commented out line //kilometers *= 2; I will get the correct answer (2 in that case). What's going wrong with the variable value that's making it behave in this way?

```
int convertLength(double *kilometers, double *miles, double *nautical_miles, double *furlongs, Scale scale) {
    switch(scale) {
        case KILOMETERS:
            printf("Kilometers was chosen\n");
            *kilometers = 1;
            *miles = 1/1.609347219;
            *nautical_miles = *miles * 1.15078;
            *furlongs = *miles / 8;
            break;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `scanf()`'s specifier, for `double` it is `"%lf"`, not `"%d"`, also

1. Turn on compiler warnings to avoid this kind of mistake, it should warn you about the incompatibility between the passed pointer and the expected pointer.
2. Check `scanf()`'s return value to ensure that your data is find instead of just assuming that it is.

Comment: Changing scanf()'s specifier to lf did the trick. What's the reason for %d not storing the correct value in value vs. %lf?

Comment: A nice terse complete answer.

Comment: @N0ug4t you should think of this, how many bits uses an `int` and how many bits are occupied by a `double`, since the `double` is wider, then not all it's bits are initialized causing undefined behavior when you use it after `scanf()`.

Comment: @CoolGuy I also do that while coding. And also, `paitner` instead of `painter`.